# Cosa significa "spiccare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> A San Paolo fuori le mura dove si accampavano gli orsineschi c'era stata battaglia grossa. Ora gli scampati fuggivano verso la città inseguiti dai colonnesi, e i cittadini radunavano i familiari e serravano i portoni. Il papa **aveva spiccato** le guardie per mettere pace, e ci sarebbe riuscito, magari con l'aiuto dei suoi svizzeri.

Malgrado abbia cercato il significato di "spiccare" in parecchi dizionari, non riesco a capire qual è il senso di questo verbo nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: lo interpreto come: "fatto uscire", "mandato", "invitato" (con celerità)

Comment: Ho la sensazione che la Bellonci ogni tanto usi termini desueti, o in modo insolito o del tutto personale, così, quasi per darsi un tono (mi perdonino i fan della scrittrice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qui il termine ***spiccare*** lo interpreto come ***distaccare***, cioè mandare, inviare le guardie che proteggevano la sua persona fuori a mettere pace, con l'aiuto delle altre guardie svizzere.

Da Treccani per [spiccare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spiccare/):

> **spiccare** v. tr. e intr. [tratto da appiccare, per sostituzione del
> pref. s- (nel sign. 1) a a-] (io spicco, tu spicchi, ecc.). – 1. tr. È
> il contrario di appiccare, e ha quindi il valore fondamentale di
> staccare ciò che è appiccato; coincide in molti usi con staccare, che,
> nella lingua parlata, è la forma più comune.

[**Distaccare**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/distaccare/) è una derivazione di staccare e, sempre da Treccani:

> Nel linguaggio milit., separare una frazione di un reparto,
> assegnandola altrove per speciali servizî (v. distaccamento).
> Analogam., d. alcuni agenti; d. un impiegato presso un altro ufficio,
> ecc.

In aggiunta a quanto già detto, volevo segnalare un estratto dalla risposta di Vittorio Coletti al quesito [*Si può spiccare una consegna?*](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/si-pu-spiccare-una-consegna/2858) posto all'Accademia della Crusca riguardo gli usi di spiccare:

> Questa fedeltà etimologica dovrebbe valere anche per il gergale
> spiccare una consegna di cui ci chiede la lettrice. Per due ragioni,
> penso: primo, perché tra i significati estesi di spiccare c’era in
> passato anche ‘mandare’, ancorché riferito soprattutto a persone
> (“spiccare ambasciatori, rinforzi”, attestati nel GDLI), da cui può
> essersi sviluppato spiccare una consegna nel senso di mandarla e
> quindi recapitarla; secondo, (e più probabile), perché una consegna
> non è solo la merce consegnata ma anche la bolla o il documento o la
> tratta ecc. che la accompagna e che quindi si emette, cioè si spicca
> nel momento in cui si avvia o si deposita al recapito la merce in
> consegna. È quello che fa pensare il significato di spiccare una
> consegna che la lettrice dichiara usato dai suoi colleghi. In questo
> senso, dunque, se consegna è una metonimia per indicare (anche) il
> documento fiscale che accompagna la merce, spiccare ha il significato
> di ‘emettere’ e il suo uso è plausibile e congruo. Il tratto gergale
> starebbe allora più nel significato dato a consegna che in quello di
> spiccare, di lunga tradizione in ambito giuridico e commerciale
> (almeno dal Cinquecento, secondo il GDLI).